# How can I get 100% happiness?

Tags: simcity-buildit

Previously, my city's population had a happiness of 100%. After some new building, their happiness dipped to about 90% (because there was no longer enough water or sewage treatment).

After fixing that (and creating more buildings) the happiness has risen to 99%. But, I cannot work out how to get that last 1%.

I have checked:

- fire stations
- police stations
- parks
- water
- power
- sewage
- traffic

It all seems to be OK. [EA answers](http://answers.ea.com/t5/SimCity-BuildIt-General/Can-t-get-happiness-higher-than-99/td-p/4554367) did not provide any new clues.

Currently, my city is at level 13.

Comment: One workaround: bulldoze recent residential buildings one at a time until the happiness increases!

Comment: This worked for me, then I upgraded existing buildings, then the level increased to 14 and now they are complaining that I'm not dealing with the garbage, so now the happiness is back to 83%!

Comment: Give it time. They slowly become happy again. You should also click on each building, often they give little tid-bits of what they would like or are currently disliking (something like "More Parks!", etc).

Comment: You may also want to make sure your roads are fully upgraded so that there are no traffic problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get more happiness, you should built some population boost building like casino, I build many of it and the happiness never dropped below 100% although I remove all the park.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check waste management and factories and whether the dirtiness from power, sewage, waste management and factories touches the houses.

Comment: OP said they were level 13

Answer (score 1):

100% Happiness does not require any population boost. Click on residential buildings and look for the negative comments, even if they have a green smiley face. You might need to move city storage or whatever your sim doesn't like being near. Also make sure your roads are upgraded and have coverage with police, fire, water, power, hospitals, waste and sewers.